# Does this Firebase info-message cause problems?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Everything is fine until the device disconnects from the internet. Of course, the streams will not work because the device is offline, but does this affect the application in other ways? Or in other words, are these messages standard when the device is offline or should I change something to handle this? The application should work offline the same as online apart from the fact the streams will not work.

Here is the message I am talking about:

```
W/ManagedChannelImpl(24903): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
W/Firestore(24903): (22.0.0) [WatchStream]: \
(fb1e6da) Stream closed with status: \
    Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, \
    description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, \
    cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: \
    Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": \
    No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore(24903): \
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:436)
W/Firestore(24903): \
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.resolveInternal(DnsNameResolver.java:272)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase applications work even a device is temporarily offline.
It is good practice that cached data is available while offline so that Firebase can resend any writes when network connectivity returns. By enabling disk persistence, the application writes data locally to the device to maintain state while offline, even if the user or operating system restarts. The code below enables disk persistence on [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Or on [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities):

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer! This sounds nice, but I have some questions after reading the documentation. I am currently using Firestore as my database. Do I have to get the FirebaseDatabase working or is there a similar thing on FirebaseFirestore? Second question: The user has to registrate in my app, so it's enough to call the method once when the user is registrating?

Comment: After reading this (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline), I think I am totally fine with firestore, as it is enabled by default. Is this right?

Comment: For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default. Only web, offline persistence is disabled.

Comment: It sounds like you will be okay. I would monitor it to be on the safe side just in case it is an issue with your code that is giving the error. Perhaps adding a handler for this error will be helpful to debug in future.

Comment: ok thanks for your opinion, appreciate it :)